# Recommended way to create an inversion of a bool value returned by a class with same interface in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a use case that involves collections of sensor objects that return a bool (indicating the state of the sensor).  In some cases the collection object is interested in the inverse of a the sensor value, but I want to use the same interface for both cases so that the collection doesn't need to track this.  An example might be

Result = sensorA | not(sensorB)

where the the value of sensorA and not(sensorB) are accessed using the same interface. I've come up with a couple of solutions for this, none of which seem as simple as I originally expected the problem to be.

Firstly, I can realize the goal by creating another class that inherits from the same base interface and performs the translation.  However this seems a little clunky as I have to instantiate a inverting object for each sensor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class ObservedSensorBase
{
public:
    virtual bool getState(void) = 0;

protected:
    ObservedSensorBase() { inverted = new InvertSensor(this); }
};

class ConcreteSensor : public ObservedSensorBase
{
public:
    ConcreteSensor(bool state) :mState(state) {}

    bool getState(void) { return mState; }
private:
    bool mState;
};

class InvertSensor : public ObservedSensorBase
{
public:
    InvertSensor(ObservedSensorBase *sensor) :mSensor(sensor) {}

    bool getState(void) { return !mSensor->getState(); }
private:
    ObservedSensorBase *mSensor;
};


int main()
{
    ConcreteSensor sensorA(true);
    InvertSensor notSensorA(&sensorA);

    vector <class ObservedSensorBas*> sensors;

    sensors.push_back(&sensorA);
    sensors.push_back(&notSensorA);

    for (class ObservedSensorBase* it : sensors)
    {
        cout << it->getState() << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

> 1
>   0

Ideally I'm looking for the original concrete sensor class to be able to return the inverted functionality.  I can do this if I add a public class to each concrete sensor:

```
class ConcreteSensor : public ObservedSensorBase
{
public:
    ConcreteSensor(bool state) :mState(state),inv(this) {}

    bool getState(void) { return mState; }

    class InvertSensor inv;
private:
    bool mState;
};

...

    sensors.push_back(&sensorA.inv);
```

Prints

> 0

but this seems a little cumbersome, as its a new variable in each concrete class. I can't add it to the base class, as InvertSensor inherits from the base, so InvertSensor isn't fully defined and can't be instantiated (at least I haven't been able to do so).

The other approach I've investigated is using an object factory:

```
ObservedSensorBase *invertFactory(ObservedSensorBase *sensor)
{
    static map<ObservedSensorBase *, ObservedSensorBase *> m;

    // Create an instance of the inverter for this object if it doesn't already exist
    if (m.find(sensor) == m.end())
    {
        m[sensor] = new InvertSensor(sensor);
    }

    // Provide the inverting object for the passed sensor
    return m[sensor];
}

...

    sensors.push_back(invertFactory(&sensorA));
```

Prints

> 0

Is there another solution that I'm missing?  Ideally something inherent in the class that each concrete instance can inherit from, but at this point it's become a bit of an intellectual challenge as well :)

--- EDIT ---
Thanks for the comments so far.

To clarify the objective better, this is for a little project for an Arduino to control signals on a model railroad.  For the purposes here, assume that the signals can only show green and red.  They show red when any track occupancy circuit or switch orientation that the signal is 'protecting' against indicates its unsafe for a train to proceed (and green otherwise).

Both the track detection and switch orientation objects would be concrete instances of the base sensor, but it's the switch orientation that creates this use case.  If we have two signals, each of which is 'protecting' the two approaches to the two-track end of a single switch, one signal will want to use the switch orientation sensor 'as-is', and the other will want to use the inverted sensor value (to represent which way the switch is thrown).

I'm wanting to be able to invert the sensors' state representation when loading the into the signal object that holds them to avoid having to store a separate 'invert this signal' indication in the signal object, or manually instantiate a separate object that performs the inversion.

So something like

Signal1 protects SensorA (trackA) and Switch B

Signal2 protects SensorC (trackC) and not(SwitchB)

Here is an example of the signal (a container of sensors that just ORs them all together) e.g.

```
class Signal
{
public:
    void protect(class ObservedSensorBase *sensor) { mSensors.push_back(sensor); }

    void periodicLoop(void)
    {
        bool anyProtectedSensorActive = false;

        for (   auto it = mSensors.begin(); 
            it != mSensors.end() && !anyProtectedSensorActive; 
            ++it) 
            { anyProtectedSensorActive |= (*it)->getState(); }

        if(anyProtectedSensorActive)    
        { /* set Signal Red */  }
        else
        { /* set signal Green */ }
    }

private:
    vector <class ObservedSensorBase*> mSensors;    // protected sensors
};

...


Signal signal1;
Signal signal2;

signal1.protect(&sensorA);
signal1.protect(&sensorB);

signal1.protect(&sensorC);
signal1.protect(&notSensorB);
```

However, after playing with @Jason C's recommendation to put something in the base class (which I couldn't get working prior to asking the question, or after his suggestion) it occured to me that I could create

```
// Invert Sensor and ObservedSensorBase are declared as above...

class InvertedSensorBase : public ObservedSensorBase
{
public:
    InvertedSensorBase() : inverted(this) {}
    class InvertSensor inverted;
};

// Change the inheritance of the concrete observer
//class ConcreteSensor : public ObservedSensorBase
class ConcreteSensor : public InvertedSensorBase
```

And now SensorA.inverted seems to fit the bill very well.

Of course, since this is mostly a side project to return to C++ and learn C++11 after a long absence, if anyone has alternate suggestions about any point, I'd be more than happy to see them.

Comment: Is there any way you can trim some paragraphs off this question?

Comment: @paddy There's only a handful and they're all short...

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't a fair comment.

Comment: can you change the `ConcreteSensor` class, if so, just add a `bool` to indicate whether or not return a inverse value. the return statement is just  `return inverse!=mState;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a *really* no-effort solution you could store `pair<ObservedSensorBase*,bool>`'s in your container, where the boolean is whether you want to invert or not, and just have your logic invert the value based on that `bool`:

```
typedef pair<ObservedSensorBase *,bool> SensorWithFlag; // ...or something

vector<SensorWithFlag> sensors;
sensors.push_back(SensorWithFlag(sensor1, true));  // invert
sensors.push_back(SensorWithFlag(sensor2, false)); // don't invert

// then later when you use it, say 'n' is an index:
bool state = (sensors[n].first->getState() != sensors[n].second);
```

---

But if not, I suppose you could do the inversion in the base:

```
class ObservedSensorBase {
    ...
public:
    void setInvertState (bool invertState) {
        invertState_ = invertState;
    }
    bool getState () {
        return invertState_ != getState_(); // != is xor
    }
protected:
    virtual bool getState_ () = 0;
private:
    bool invertState_;
};
```

Then all subclasses implement `getState_` instead of `getState`, and all have the ability to have their results inverted by setting `setInvertState(true)`.

But this seems weird. Perhaps you could add some more details about how your containers are using these values. I feel like there may be a better way in general to structure your program and algorithms.

---

Another option is to use your "inverting filter" option but manage it in the base:

```
class ObservedSensorBase {
    ...
public:
    ObservedSensorBase (...) : inv_(this) { ... }
    InvertSensor * inverted () { return &inv_; }
private:
    InvertSensor inv_;
};
```

Then you can just add `mySensor->inverted()` to your container when needed. This has the following caveats:

- Do not call any virtual methods of `ObservedSensorBase` from `InvertSensor`'s constructor.
- Do not call any methods of `InvertSensor` that may lead to virtual base methods being called, from `ObservedSensorBase`'s constructor.
- Pointer returned by `inverted()` is invalidated when sensor is deleted.

The first two points are important because `this` won't be fully constructed yet when constructing subclasses.

This way, every sensor automatically has an inverted version of itself that comes along with it, and you don't have to manage them manually.

---

Yet another solution is to create wrappers around sensor objects, but keep them simple and store them directly in containers instead of storing pointers to them, to keep memory management easier. For example:

```
class SensorValue {
public:
    SensorValue (ObservedSensorBase *s, bool invert) 
        : s_(s), i_(invert) { }
    bool getState () { return i_ != s_->getState(); }
    ObservedSensorBase * sensor () { return s_; }
private:
    ObservedSensorBase *s_;
    bool i_;
};

// then later, let's say you have some sensors:
ObservedSensorBase *sensor1 = ...;
ObservedSensorBase *sensor2 = ...;

// you can have containers like this:
vector<SensorValue> collection1, collection2;

// and you can use normal/inverted states as needed:
collection1.push_back(SensorValue(sensor1, false)); // normal values
collection1.push_back(SensorValue(sensor2, false)); 
collection2.push_back(SensorValue(sensor1, true));  // and inverted 
collection2.push_back(SensorValue(sensor2, true));  // at the same time

// if you ever need the sensor object itself you can use SensorValue#sensor:
for (vector<SensorValue>::iterator i = collection1.begin();
     i != collection1.end(); ++ i) 
{
    bool state = i->getState(); // normal or inverted, transparent to us here
    ObservedSensorBase *sensor = i->sensor(); // can be used for whatever.
    // note that i->getState() != i->sensor()->getState() if we're
    // using an inverted SensorValue.
}

// and they aren't pointers, you can just do this with no leaks:
collection1.clear();
collection2.clear();

// although of course you still do this for sensor cleanup:
delete sensor2;
delete sensor1;
```

This is *sort of* conceptually like your inverted sensor object approach except `SensorValue` isn't an `ObservedSensorBase`, it's lightweight and cheaply copyable, and you can just store them directly in containers instead of passing around pointers.

It's very similar to storing e.g. `pair<ObservedSensorBase*,bool>` (where you store sensor and invert flag) in your containers instead, except unlike `pair` it gives you a convenient `getState()` member, and has some semantic meaning.

Comment: For adding to the base, I'd still have to declare a separate object, and possibly a separate concrete instance that monitors the same piece of HW - so I'd basically end up with much the same as my original solution?    

Your second suggestion is something I tried originally but couldn't get to work (I think this applies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889713/forward-declaration-of-class-in-c ?), but it got me thinking about a solution I think does work (see the bottom of my edit).

Comment: @ksi_help I'm not sure if you'd have to declare a separate object because I don't know how you're using it. If at any point in time you're interested in both the normal *and* inverted values of a sensor then it would not be a good solution. But if you're only ever interested in one or the other you can `setInvertState()` as needed on one object. Your edit sort of looks like my second suggestion.

Comment: @ksi_help Btw you appear to be coming from C. You can just do `Inverted inverted;`, you don't need to prefix it with `class Inverted inverted;`. Also you can leave the `void` out of empty function parameter lists, `bool getState ()` instead of `bool getState (void)`.

Comment: I am wanting to use both the normal and inverted values of the sensor, which wasn't originally clear but hopefully my edit has clarified this.  And you are right, I am coming from a C background, so the style comments are appreciated.

Comment: @ksi_help Check out the third option I just added.

Comment: @ksi_help You could also use a `pair`. I added that at the top, too. All right, I'm done bombarding you with comment pings.

Comment: OK, that third options looks very promising.  Since this will be running on an Arduino with all of the sensors statically allocated memory management is less of a problem, but it looks like a better OO solution to the original problem.
It would probably take more RAM (since a SensorValue object is needed each time a sensor is used) but it certainly answers the original question of looking for another alternative.